# Wordpress How to add class to <ul> of sidebar widget

Tags: wordpress

This is how I register the sidebar:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'First_sidebar',
    'id' => 'sidebar-1',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="well">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h4>',
    'after_title' => '</h4>'
));
```

and this is the HTML WordPress output:

```
<div class="well">
<h4>title</h4>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to add a `class` attribute to the `<ul>` tag.
Like this:

```
<div class="well">
    <h4>title</h4>
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How do I add the `class` attribute to `<ul>`?

Comment: Can't you just modify the sidebar.php?

Comment: I use dynamic_sidebar function

Comment: Same issue here since I wanted to add BS nav class to the ul. I edited /wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php Modify the $defaults array inside of function wp_nav_menu()... add the markup you require to 'items_wrap'. Hacky but a start. WP 4.7.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple, but not so nice and more of a hack, is using Javascript/jQuery.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.widget > ul').addClass('nav nav-list');
});
```

I really dislike using javascript, but it does the job in this case.

Comment: Just in case, there are quite a few ways to add javascript to wordpress. Some more correct than others but you can refer to (the documentation)[https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript]

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do it this way:

Sidebar.php:

```
<!-- sidebar -->
<aside class="sidebar" role="complementary">

<div class="sidebar-widget">
  <?php if(function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')) {

    ob_start();
    dynamic_sidebar('widget-area-1');
    $sidebar = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $sidebar_corrected_ul = str_replace("<ul>", '<ul class="menu vertical">', $sidebar);

    echo $sidebar_corrected_ul;
    } 

  ?>
</div>

</aside>
<!-- /sidebar -->
```

I used output buffering to save the sidebar widgets into a variable and then used string replace to find all `<ul>` tags and replace them with the `<ul>` tag with the class.

Answer (score 1):

Use Less:

```
.widget ul {
    .nav;
    .nav-pills;
    .nav-stacked;
}
```

it worked for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

I played around with it and this works for me.

```
function create_widget( $name, $id, $class, $description ) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __( $name ),
        'id' => $id,
        'class' => $class,
        'description' => __( $description ),
        'before_widget' => '<div ' . 'class ='. $class . '>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2>'
    ));

create_widget( 'widget name', 'myID', 'myClass', 'my description' );
```

Comment: you should also add few lines of description to explain your logic/code

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you are looking for is `'class'         => ''`

For you, you need:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'First_sidebar',
    'id' => 'sidebar-1',
    'class'         => 'nav-list',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="well">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h4>',
    'after_title' => '</h4>'
));
```

That should work.

Comment: hey, can you post your code here so i could take a look?

Comment: I have exactly [this problem](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113233/howto-add-class-to-sidebar-widget-list-items#)

Comment: the (doc)[http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar] says:  class - CSS class name to assign to the widget HTML (default: empty).

Comment: the 'class' property adds the class to the entire sidebar, not to the widget's ul.
you should use 'before_widget' to place the div with a class name and then with the css go to it as: `.className ul{ /* properties */ } `

Comment: that is right, except that I am using bootstrap, and I need to add the class in `ul` to use the style. Otherwise change the sources of bootstrap.

Comment: You can use jquery to do that: `$('.className ul').addClass('newClassNameToAdd');`

Comment: From the Codex: "class - CSS class to assign to the Sidebar in the Appearance -> Widget admin page. This class will only appear in the source of the WordPress Widget admin page. It will not be included in the frontend of your website. "

Comment: Hey @Edd please provide a link to where you have read it, i think you misunderstood it.... i know for a fact that this works...

Comment: @EliranEfron, here it is: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar  - look for the Parameters part. It didn't work for me...

Comment: well it used to work... any way you can still use the `before_widget` to write the div wrapper with the class you want and then go `.class_name ul{ /* css code */}`

Answer (score 0):

There is a native solution to add the individual widget names as className using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to their container:

`%1$s` represents the id and `%2$s` the widgets className

There is no need to add the className directly to the `<ul>` because of this possible selector(jQuery/CSS):

```
.widget_nav-list > ul (.widget_nav_menu > ul)
```

also note that the answered jQuery code targets all widgets in all sidebars, even if they are no nav-list (what can be OK if your only used widget is a nav).

> before_widget - HTML to place before every widget(default: `<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">`) Note: uses sprintf for variable substitution

[Reference on wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar#Default_Usage)

functions.php:

```
register_sidebar(array(
  'name' => 'First_sidebar',
  'id' => 'sidebar-1',
  'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="well %2$s">',
  'after_widget' => '</div>',
  'before_title' => '<h4>',
  'after_title' => '</h4>'
));
```

Output for a default navigation widget:

```
<div id="nav_menu-1" class="well widget_nav_menu">
  <h4>title</h4>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

i am posting at this old thread because it was a top search result for the search term "register_sidebar widgetname" - so i thought having an complete answer is good here.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom WordPress widget: (No need for jQuery or any Plugin!!)

My steps will go through with categories widget and you can do the same for any widget.

1. Register Widget (in functions.php)

```
    add_action('widgets_init', 'register_widgets');
    function register_widgets($id) {
      register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Sidebar',
        'id'  => 'sidebar'
      ));
    }
```

2. Register Custom Widget (in functions.php)

```
    add_action('widgets_init', 'register_custom_widget');
    function register_custom_widget() {
      register_widget('WP_Widget_Categories_Custom');
    }
```

3. Copy file class-wp-widget-categories.php from /wp-includes/widgets/ and put it beside your theme files /wp-content/themes/-your theme-/widgets/
4. Include this file in functions.php

   `require_once('widgets/class-wp-widget-categories.php');`
5. Rename class name from "WP_Widget_Categories" to "WP_Widget_Categories_Custom" in "widgets/class-wp-widget-categories.php" file.

   `class WP_Widget_Categories_Custom extends WP_Widget {`
6. Search about **ul** tag in "widgets/class-wp-widget-categories.php" file and edit it like

   `<ul class="nav nav-list">`

That is all ;)

Answer (score 0):

This would replace all opening ul tags and li tags:

```
<?php 

  if(function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')) {

    ob_start();
    dynamic_sidebar('news-sidebar');
    $news_sidebar = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $news_sidebar_corrected_ul_and_li = str_replace('<ul>', '<ul class="list-group mb-20">', str_replace('<li>', '<li class="list-group-item rounded-0">', $news_sidebar));
    echo $news_sidebar_corrected_ul_and_li;
  } 

?>
```

To Avoid conflicts with unwantend replacement i would recomment tu not use ul and li inside 
'before_widget'and 'before_title' like:

```
register_sidebar( array(
  'name'          => __( 'news-sidebar'),
  'id'            => 'news-sidebar',
  'description'   => '',
  'class'         => 'card-body border-bottom px-0 px-md-20',
  'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="w-100 widget-%2$s">',
  'after_widget'  => '</div>' ,
  'before_title'  => '<div class="card-header p-10 p-md-20 h5 bg-light">',
  'after_title'   => '</div>'  
)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
in function.php

     register_sidebar( array(
                "id" => "contactform",
                "name" => "lorm text",
                "description" => "lorm text",
                "before_widget" => "",
                "after_widget" => "",
            ));

in .php file

     

      <div class="feature_h">
                <?php if(is_active_sidebar( 'contactform' )) 
                    dynamic_sidebar( 'contactform' );
                ?>   
            </div>

in .js file

    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.feature_h > h2').addClass('mb-3 text-white');
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I was struggling against this problem and I discovered that you can use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-bootstrap-navmenu

Answer (score -2):

you can use a plugin that called widget-css-class
[WordPress directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-css-classes/)

after that you will be able to add custom css class to any widgets that you need.

Comment: Installing an entire plugin for such a small feature will quickly bloat your environment. Also this plugin seems it allows you the option within the WP-Admin, it seems the OP is looking to handle this within `.php` template files.